# Difuminación de la imagen al rotarla en java

Tags: java, animación

Como escribí en el titulo de la pregunta, una imagen al rotarla se difumina. Se ven unos pixeles con el mismo color que el JFrame en que se encuentra la imagen.

Les dejo un link a un video para que puedan ver mejor lo que les comenté: [(video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2G7p6c-mw-E)

Les dejo el codigo donde se rota la imagen:

```
public Image rotarImagen(int angulo, int largo, int alto) {
    BufferedImage retorno=new BufferedImage(largo,alto,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    int x,y;
    for(int i=-imagen.getIconWidth()/2;i<imagen.getIconWidth()/2;i++) {
        for(int j=-imagen.getIconHeight()/2;j<imagen.getIconHeight()/2;j++) {
            x= (int)((i)*Math.cos((angulo*Math.PI)/180)-(j)*Math.sin((angulo*Math.PI)/180));
            y=(int)((j)*Math.cos((angulo*Math.PI)/180)+(i)*Math.sin((angulo*Math.PI)/180));
            retorno.setRGB(largo/2+x, alto/2+y,arreglo[(imagen.getIconWidth()/2)+i][(imagen.getIconHeight()/2)+j]); 
        }
    }
    return retorno;
}
```

Saludos

Comment: Espero que esta liga te ayude un poco con las transformaciones afines: https://www.javaworld.com/article/2076733/antialiasing--images--and-alpha-compositing-in-java-2d.html?page=2

Comment: Gracias Ruslan Lopez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Publico la respuesta para que le sirva a alguien en el futuro que tenga el mismo problema.
Lo que hay que hacer es multiplicar por un numero entre 0 y 1 la coordenada x e y.Lo que provocara que la imagen reduzca su tamaño, en este caso lo multiplique por 0.5, es decir,se reduce su tamaño a la mitad. Por lo tanto tendrian que agrandarla al doble con el metodo getScaledInstance().
Finalmente el codigo del metodo quedaria asi (hice otros cambios igual al metodo):

```
   public Image rotarImagen(int angulo, int largo, int alto) {
    BufferedImage retorno=new BufferedImage(largo,alto,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    double x,y;
    int mitadX=imagen.getIconWidth()/2;
    int mitadY=imagen.getIconHeight()/2;
    double anguloAux=(angulo*Math.PI)/180;
    for(int i=-imagen.getIconWidth()/2;i<imagen.getIconWidth()/2;i++) {
        for(int j=-imagen.getIconHeight()/2;j<imagen.getIconHeight()/2;j++) {
           x=0.5*(i*Math.cos(anguloAux)-j*Math.sin(anguloAux));
           y=0.5*(j*Math.cos(anguloAux)+i*Math.sin(anguloAux));

           retorno.setRGB((int)((largo/2)+x),(int)((alto/2)+y),arreglo[mitadX+i][mitadY+j]); 
        }
    }
    return retorno;
}
```

Comment: Recuerda marcarla como aceptada para que otros sepan que tiene solución :)